# How to use ssh with github, it seems it's switching to https all by itself?

Tags: git, github

I cloned a repo using the "ssh" method, but then, there is a the https method in remote, and git push is asking password ??

```
git clone git@github.com:julienfr112/random.git
cd random
git remote -v
```

> ```
> origin    https://github.com/julienfr112/random.git (fetch)
>
> origin    https://github.com/julienfr112/random.git (push)
> ```

```
cat .git/config
```

> ```
> [remote "origin"]
>
> url = git@github.com:julienfr112/random.git
>
> fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> ```

What the heck ?

Comment: If you run `git config -l`, are there any entries that contain `insteadOf` in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the SSH Key to your github account???

If yes, then try setting the remote origin using the following command:

git remote set-url origin git@github.com:**USERNAME**/**REPOSITORY**.git

If no, you need to add the SSH key to your account first and then try...

Hope it helps...